# Windows 10 Project screens are backwards

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, projector

I'm running Windows 10 with all the latest updates. When I click on Project from the Settings menu my screens are backwards. It says my 2 primary monitors (DVI) are my "Secondary Screen" and my projector (HDMI) is my "PC Screen". How to I flip them to be the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the screen you wish to be the the main one in the Display Settings dialog, and then check the box "Make this my main display" and click Apply.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. It isn't about setting the primary display, it's about the Project charm in Action Center. Click the Action Center icon in the system tray and then click Project.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that your computer identifies the HDMI connection as the primary connection, which doesn't make a lot of sense as a default because, while HDMI is nice, it's still more common on projectors than on monitors. I've not seen this issue before, and it seems not many people online have either, or I haven't found the right words to google with. I'll keep digging for a bit though.